# Concurrent Execution of Workflow and Activities in One Worker Instance

Tags: python, concurrent.futures, temporal, temporal-workflow

I hope this message finds you well. I’m currently working on Temporal Implementation for managing workflows execution. I’ve encountered a challenge and would greatly appreciate your insights and expertise to help me overcome it.

**Issue/Question:**

We are running the worker as a POD (replica 1 - we don’t want to run more than 1) in cluster. We want to execute multiple workflow at the same time and get the output without waiting for the current workflow to complete it execution (we want parallel execution in same instance of worker)

**Steps I’ve Taken:**

I have configured the max concurrency of workflow and task in worker side configuration

**Code or Configuration:**

```py
def slp(sec):
    sleep(sec)
    return f"slept {sec} sec"

@activity.defn(name="Sleeping 1")
async def sleeping1():
    response = slp(20)
    return response

@activity.defn(name="sleeping 2")
async def sleeping2():
    response = slp(120)
    return response

@workflow.defn
class sleepingWF:
    @workflow.run
    async def run(self, body):

        s1 = await workflow.execute_activity(
            sleeping1))
        s2 = await workflow.execute_activity(
            sleeping2)) 
        
async def main():

    TEMPORAL_ENDPOINT = "localhost:7233"
    TASK_QUEUE = "mymac"

    client = await Client.connect(
        target_host=TEMPORAL_ENDPOINT
    )
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=100) as activity_executor:
        worker = Worker(
            client,
            task_queue=TASK_QUEUE,
            workflows=[sleepingWF],
            activities=[sleeping1, sleeping2],
            activity_executor=activity_executor,
            max_concurrent_workflow_tasks=100,
            max_concurrent_activities=100,
            max_concurrent_workflow_task_polls=10,
            max_concurrent_activity_task_polls=10,
        )
        await worker.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

I truly appreciate your time and assistance. If you have any suggestions, insights, or possible solutions, please feel free to share them. Your expertise is invaluable, and I look forward to learning from the community.

**Expected Outcome:**

```
workflow_execution_1 : start_time -> 00:00:00 end_time -> 00:02:20
workflow_execution_2 : start_time -> 00:00:00 end_time -> 00:02:20
```

Total time take for two execution should be 140 sec

**Environment:**
python 11

**Additional Information:**

**Current total execution time taken:**

```
workflow_execution_1 : start_time -> 00:00:00 end_time -> 00:02:20
workflow_execution_2 : start_time -> 00:02:20 end_time -> 00:04:40
```

Total time take for two execution takes 280 sec now

Comment: How are you starting the Workflow Executions?

Comment: @James I have two different client.py files and running them paralley. I can see both execution in running state in temporal UI as well. I’m not starting one-by-one

Comment: It would be very useful to see the workflow histories for these two executions. Can you please [export these two histories](https://docs.temporal.io/dev-guide/python/durable-execution#via-the-ui) and share them here? You can copy the history in JSON format, and share them as [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) or [gist](https://gist.github.com/), or take screenshots from the Web UI's history in compact view.

Comment: I'd expect your start times and end times to be more like this:

`workflow_execution_1 : start_time ->  00:00:00  end_time -> *00:02:40*`
`workflow_execution_2 : start_time -> *00:00:00* end_time ->  00:04:40`

Comment: Also, I observe that you configured your activities to run through a `ThreadPoolExecutor`. Why? Was this an attempt at resolving the present issue, or something deliberate you did for other reasons?

Comment: Can you just replace the `sleep()` at line 2 by `asyncio.sleep()`, or do you really need it to be blocking?

Comment: my-workflow-id0: https://pastebin.com/jwHmwq6s
my-workflow-id1: https://pastebin.com/XSYG8aJB
I configured activities to run through a ThreadPoolExecutor, this was mentioned in Documentation

Comment: Thanks, but these histories only show the very first event; it should contain at least 18 events. In recent UI, while looking at the workflow history, you need to click the Download button rather the JSON one.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: I'm still not yet sure what is happening and why, but in the meantime, let me expose a possible explanation and solutions.*

**TLDR**

The call to `sleep()` at line 2 seems to block concurrent execution other threads.

Try one of these solutions:

- Replace `sleep()` by `asyncio.sleep()` (and then, you can remove the `ThreadPoolExecutor` altogether); or
- Make sure you are using a recent release of Python and the Temporal's Python SDK; or
- Use a `ProcessPoolExecutor` instead of a `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

**Details**

By default, the Temporal's Python SDK executes both workflow tasks and activity tasks in a single thread, based on `asyncio`. As stated in [Python SDK's documentation](https://docs.temporal.io/dev-guide/python/foundations#develop-activities):

> Blocking the async event loop in Python would turn your asynchronous program into a synchronous program that executes serially, defeating the entire purpose of using asyncio. This can also lead to potential deadlock, and unpredictable behavior that causes tasks to be unable to execute. Debugging these issues can be difficult and time consuming, as locating the source of the blocking call might not always be immediately obvious.

It is often possible, and preferable, to design your activities to not block the thread. For example, if your activities need to perform SQL queries, HTTP requests, download from or upload to S3, then you can use asyncio compatible libraries. In the case of the `sleep()` at line 2, you can use `asyncio.sleep()` instead.

If you really need to execute blocking code from your activities, for example if your activities run long CPU intensive logic, then you may instead configure your worker to execute activities through a `ThreadPoolExecutor` or a `ProcessPoolExecutor`.

Yet, you apparently did the former, and it didn't work. Why? I suppose that's due to the fact that the `sleep` function isn't releasing Python's Global Interpreter Lock (GIL), though I'm not sure why.

If you don't already know what is Python's GIL, I strongly suggest you get a look to answers on [that other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294382/what-is-the-global-interpreter-lock-gil-in-cpython) before you continue reading my answer.

The key thing to note here is that Python's GIL is *per-process*, not *per-thread* as one would generally expect. That considerably limit the level of concurrency you may actually expect from a `ThreadPoolExecutor`. Or put another way, `ThreadPoolExecutor` will only help if your code is calling a native code that releases the GIL, doing I/O operations, or calling some other functions provided by Python that similarly release the GIL. Otherwise, other threads won't get the chance to continue executing.

I suppose that by `sleep()`, you are really talking about `time.sleep()`, right? `time.sleep()` is expected to release the GIL, though it looks like it isn't in your case. Could it be that `sleep()`, at line 2 in your code, is actually referring to a different function?

**How to diagnose this kind of problem?**

In your question, you gave these timing:

```
workflow_execution_1 : start_time -> 00:00:00 end_time -> 00:02:20
workflow_execution_2 : start_time -> 00:02:20 end_time -> 00:04:40
```

I doubt these numbers are correct, as these would mean your second workflow execution don't get started until the first one complete, but in comments, you clearly indicated that you are starting both workflows at the same time.

I'd rather expect your timing to be roughly:

```
workflow_execution_1 : start_time ->  00:00:00  end_time -> *00:02:40*
workflow_execution_2 : start_time -> *00:00:00* end_time ->  00:04:40
```

Examining the Workflow History is really the best way to understand what's happening. Here's an example of what you should see in the Temporal UI assuming that there is no blocking-sleep issue. Both workflow executions should look the same:

[image]

The Workflow's start time and end time are the ones shown in the green boxes. You may also see the start and end time of your sleep activities (the blue boxes). It's also possible you may see some non-negligible time being spent in workflow task processing, or even time out errors, which would point at other issues.

If my previous suggestions haven't been enough to resolve your issue, please share a picture like that one of both workflow histories, or even better, share the full history in JSON format (press the Download button). Make sure to wait for your workflows to have completed before you capture history. Given the workflow code you shared, there should be at least 17 events in the history when the workflow completes, and the very last event in both history should be a `WorkflowExecutionCompleted`.

There's a lot to be said about Temporal's workflow history, more than I can write here. If you haven't yet done so, I suggest you take [Temporal's 101 and 102 courses](https://learn.temporal.io/courses/); both are available in Python. Among other things, these courses explain how to read the workflow history to debug various type of issues.

Comment: Thank you James. I will try all the suggestions and post the solution if succeed else I will post the entire workflow logs for further reference. Thanks again!